# HTTP Error 500.32 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core Hosting how can I solve this?

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core Web API into an IIS site in windows 2012 server, I've installed IIS from 0 and when I deploy the app and test a petition with Postman I get the `500.32 error`.

I've already installed the .NET Core hosting bundle v 6.0.14 also I've configured the application pool to no managed code and I restarted all the services including the IIS.

Restarted the server isn't an option because I can't get physical access to the server, I'm working from a remote location

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utA9a.png) is my `dotnet --info`

I'm trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API.

I've already done:

- Compile and publish the API
- Installed the is
- Create a site and application to deploy the API
- Paste the files from the publish folder to the site folder
- Installed the netcore hosting bundle

Comment: Try running the application directly using `Powershell` and see the output. What error it is throwing?

Comment: when i trying to run from a powershell the api works fine in the port 5000

Comment: A more detailed report is needed to learn your setup, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run it and attach to the question body.

Comment: I had this error when publishing self-contained with in-process hosting.  (self-contained doesn't support in-process)  I turned of self-contained publishing and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the compilation and publish process.
i had to add the check for Ready to run in the publish configurations, i put that and solved the issue